# spring - override current hadoop kerberos user using ugi

Tags: spring, hadoop, spring-data

My application runs on webserver but the weberserver user doesnt have a kerberos account .. so when starting spring hadoop configuration it fails. I do have another kerberos user with a keytab file that I can login with but before I get the chance to do that spring already tries to set the configuration with the current linux user and fails. This is how I am using the other user

```
UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(userId, userKeyTabFilePath);
```

currently I am calling this from WebApplicationInitializer.onStartup method but it still fails in setting up the configuration for spring hadoop stuff (possibly FileSystem) because it doesnt uses the user that I am logging here. How can I override the spring setting up hadoop configuration process to provide this user as the logged in user instead of current linux user.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

configuring hadoop with kerberos is a real pain. The easiest thing to fix this problem is to run your application with a jaas.conf which has the necessary credentials and keytab, besides using UGI.

Here's an example config:

```
Client {
 com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
 useKeyTab=true
 keyTab="/etc/tomcat/<keytab>"
 storeKey=true
 useTicketCache=false
 principal="<user>@<host>";
};
```

pass the

```
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=<path to jaas.conf>
```

vm param to your web application container.

I assume that your spring config already loads the *-site.xml files from your hadoop. That's necessary too.